# Putting text after only the first result of loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I have this loop.

```
foreach ($html2->find('.entry-content img') as $image) {
    $path = $image->src;    
    $start = '<img src="'.$path.'" style="height: auto; width: 100%;margin-bottom: 3px;">';
    print htmlspecialchars($start); print '<br>';
}
```

Which is scraping some images from a website using **simple_html_dom.php**, that part is working perfectly. However I need to make it so that it returns the WordPress `<!--more-->` tag after the first result **only** within the foreach loop.

How can I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking if it's the first one during the loop, like this:

```
$first = TRUE;

foreach ($html2->find('.entry-content img') as $image) {
$path = $image->src;    
$start = '<img src="'.$path.'" style="height: auto; width: 100%;margin-bottom: 3px;">';

if($first){
    $start .= "<!--more-->";
    $first  = FALSE;
}

print htmlspecialchars($start); print '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `if` can do the job

```
$cond = false;
foreach($html2->find('.entry-content img') as $image) {
//Always done
if (!$cond) {
  //Will be called only during the first iterration
  $cond = true;
 }
else if ($cond){
  //This part will always be executed after the first iterration
 }
}
```